# Why? No handlers could be found for logger "oslo_config.cfg"

Tags: openstack

When I follow the install-guide of openstack(liberty) to install openstack on centos7 server, I meet below error after I execute command：

```
/bin/sh -c "keystone-manage db_sync" keystone
```

Error info:

```
[root@node0 opt]# /bin/sh -c "keystone-manage db_sync" keystone
No handlers could be found for logger "oslo_config.cfg"
```

I also execute the command like this:

```
[root@node0 opt]#su -s /bin/sh -c "keystone-manage db_sync" keystone
No handlers could be found for logger "oslo_config.cf
```

The error appears too!

Can anybody help me to fix this error? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading python-oslo package, that should solve it.